# How to use synchronous calling in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, synchronous

I use following method in react to call getUser from userService and get data for a respective user id which is passed in the getUser function. But this is done in asynchronous way, means our render method complete execution before this call to getUser completed and and 'user' state is setted. I want to done this in synchronous way, so that our render method execute after data is returned and and state in setted.
How will I do that.

```
componentWillMount() {
    var id = this.props.match.params.id;

    UserService.getUser(id)
    .then(res => {this.setState({
                user : res.data
            });
            console.log(this.state.user);
        });

  };
```

I use componentWillMount() because this executes before render method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to render something before the `user` is loaded for better user experiences, preferably a loading indication, or just nothing. But never freeze the process or just wait a promise to be resolved.

In the `render` method, do something similar to this:

```js
render() {
    if (!this.state.user) {
        return null;    // Or render something else before the user is loaded
    } else {
        return <SomeElement user={this.state.user} />;
    }
}
```

Also for better practice, do data fetching in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook instead, it's much consistent.